# Ajax call with Rgraph not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, rgraph

I have the following weird problem. I have an HTML page that has some RGraph gauges, which I want to update at regular intervals using Ajax.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
var update = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : "update.php",
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (json) {
            meterWind.set('value',json['hum']);                         
        }
    });
};
$('#test').click(function(){
    update();
});
setInterval(update, 2000);
```

The json output is ok, I checked it with an alert and it does return a value, for some reason the gauge was not updating. So to test it further I created a button "test" and set the function update() to trigger when test is clicked.

Now for some reason, when I click the test button, the gauge updates as it should - which suggests that the update() function works, just try clicking the test button several times.

However, no matter what I do and tried, when I trigger the function with the setInterval, the gauge does not change... weird, any suggestions?

http://meteotemplate.com/templateTest/testing/index.html

I also tried setting the interval on the "click" and when I put alert in the click, it alerts, but again, no update on the gauge.

```
var x = setInterval(function(){ $('#test').trigger("click");}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Reviewing the code that you provided, following change (success callback for your ajax request) made it to work. Meaning that basically after any change you need to update the `UI` by calling `draw()` method.

```
success : function (json) {
    meterWind.set('value',json['hum']);
    meterWind.draw();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it

Comment: Cool! ... so, isn't it the best answer? :)

Comment: As well as calling the .draw() nethod again you can use the RGraph.redraw() function which will cause *all* canvas tags on the page to be redrawn.